# Getting all nodes related to an specific node but not to another

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Having this model:

```
(:Person)-[:has]-(:Movie)
```

I need to get all the movies that an arbitrary group of people have but another one does not.

I started with:

```
MATCH (p1.Person {Name: 'Josh'})-[:has]->(m:Movie)
WHERE not exists ((p2:Person {Name: 'Carl'})-[:has]->(m))
RETURN COUNT(m)
```

And I get the number of movies that p1 has and p2 does not.
The problem is that I need the same with groups, not individuals; something like:

```
MATCH (p1.Person {Name: ['Josh','Mark]})-[:has]->(m:Movie)
WHERE 
not exists ((p2:Person {Name: ['Carl','Roger']})-[:has]->(m))
RETURN COUNT(m)
```

I would need an equivalent query that returns the movies that Josh AND Mark have and Carl AND Roger don't.

Any sugestion?

Comment: Do you need to consider the movie that Josh has, but which Mark, Carl and Roger do not have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass your person-name lists as 2 [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) (say, `yes` and `no`), you can avoid modifying the Cypher code for different combinations of names.

For example:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:has]->(m1:Movie)
WHERE p1.Name IN $no
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT m1) AS blacklist
MATCH (p2:Person)-[:has]->(m2:Movie)
WHERE p2.Name IN $yes AND NOT (m2 IN blacklist)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT m2);
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword is used to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NONE` predicate :

```
MATCH (person:Person) WHERE person.Name IN ['Carl', 'Roger']
WITH collect(person) AS blacklist
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:has]->(m:Movie)
WHERE p1.Name IN ['Josh', 'Mark']
AND NONE 
    ( p2 IN blacklist
         WHERE EXISTS( (p2)-[:has]->(m)) 
    )
RETURN COUNT(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
// Match p1 (Josh and Mark)
MATCH (p1:Person)
WHERE p1.name in ['Josh','Mark']
// Match p2 (Carl and Roger)
MATCH (p2:Person)
WHERE p2.name in ['Carl','Roger']
// Match movies that p1 group have but p2 does not
MATCH (p1)-[:has]->(m:Movie)
WHERE NOT (p2)-[:has]->(m:Movie)
// return the count
RETURN COUNT(m)
```